# Как на Си передать информацию от микроконтроллера на COM-порт?

Tags: c++, c, микроконтроллеры, com-порт

Занимаюсь изучением программирования микроконтроллеров `АВР`, и столкнулся с вопросом передачи данных от микроконтроллера на ПК через ком порт. Пишу на Си, `МК Atmel AtMega32`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для передачи информации от МК на COM-порт ПК используется интерфейс RS-232. На микроконтроллерах AVR он называется USART(универсальный синхронно-асинхронный приемо передатчик). 
Вы написали, что программа на Си, но не указали какой компилятор Вы используете, поэтому ниже приведу программу написанную в CodeVision AVR, но перенести ее на любой другой C компилятор микроконтроллеров AVR не должно составить особых сложностей.
Есть два пути создания такого рода ПО.
1) Воспользоваться стандартным генератором начального кода, который имеется в CodeVisionAVR. Для этого нужно выполнить следующие шаги.

```
а) при создании нового проекта, выбрать "использовать CodeWizard"
б) перейти на вкладку USART и там поставить галочки перед приемником и передатчиком, то есть активизировать их.
в) задать скорость приема передачи информации и другие параметры, синхронность асинхронность, кол-во стоп битов и т.д.
г) нажать генерировать ПО
д) далее используя стандартную библиотеку ввода-вывода отправлять и принимать информацию.
```

2) Написать ручками ниже приведенный код:

```
 #include <mega32.h> 
     #include <delay.h> 
     #include <stdio.h>

     void main(void) 
     {

     // Input/Output Ports initialization 
     // Port A initialization 
     // Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
     // State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
     PORTA=0x00; 
     DDRA=0x00;

     // Port B initialization 
     // Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=Out Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
     // State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=0 State2=T State1=T State0=T 
     PORTB=0x00; 
     DDRB=0x0C;

     // Port C initialization 
     // Func7=Out Func6=Out Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=Out Func0=Out 
     // State7=0 State6=0 State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=0 State0=0 
     PORTC=0x00; 
     DDRC=0xC3;

     // Port D initialization 
     // Func7=Out Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
     // State7=0 State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
     PORTD=0x00; 
     DDRD=0x88;

     // Timer/Counter 0 initialization 
     // Clock source: System Clock 
     // Clock value: 250,000 kHz 
     // Mode: Fast PWM top=FFh 
     // OC0 output: Non-Inverted PWM 
     TCCR0=0x6B; 
     TCNT0=0x00; 
     OCR0=0x5F;

     // Timer/Counter 1 initialization 
     // Clock source: System Clock 
     // Clock value: Timer 1 Stopped 
     // Mode: Normal top=FFFFh 
     // OC1A output: Discon. 
     // OC1B output: Discon. 
     // Noise Canceler: Off 
     // Input Capture on Falling Edge 
     // Timer 1 Overflow Interrupt: Off 
     // Input Capture Interrupt: Off 
     // Compare A Match Interrupt: Off 
     // Compare B Match Interrupt: Off 
     TCCR1A=0x00; 
     TCCR1B=0x00; 
     TCNT1H=0x00; 
     TCNT1L=0x00; 
     ICR1H=0x00; 
     ICR1L=0x00; 
     OCR1AH=0x00; 
     OCR1AL=0x00; 
     OCR1BH=0x00; 
     OCR1BL=0x00;

     // Timer/Counter 2 initialization 
     // Clock source: System Clock 
     // Clock value: 250,000 kHz 
     // Mode: Fast PWM top=FFh 
     // OC2 output: Non-Inverted PWM 
     ASSR=0x00; 
     TCCR2=0x6C; 
     TCNT2=0x00; 
     OCR2=0x5F;

     // External Interrupt(s) initialization 
     // INT0: Off 
     // INT1: Off 
     // INT2: Off 
     MCUCR=0x00; 
     MCUCSR=0x00;

     // Timer(s)/Counter(s) Interrupt(s) initialization 
     TIMSK=0x00;

     /// USART initialization 
     // Параметры соединения: 8 Data, 1 Stop, No Parity 
     // USART Receiver: On 
     // USART Transmitter: On 
     // USART Mode: Asynchronous 
     // USART Baud Rate: 38400 
     UCSRA=0x00; 
     UCSRB=0x18; 
     UCSRC=0x86; 
     UBRRH=0x00; 
     UBRRL=0x19;

     // Analog Comparator initialization 
     // Analog Comparator: Off 
     // Analog Comparator Input Capture by Timer/Counter 1: Off 
     ACSR=0x80; 
     SFIOR=0x00;

    while (1) 
     { 
     int a;
     a = 5;
     unsigned char get;
    // Отправить что нибудь:
    printf("%d\n\r", a);
    // Принять
    get = getchar();
    //Отправить принятое:
    printf("%d\n\r", get);
     }
     }
```

Но не забывайте, прежде чем организовать прием-передачу информации посредством RS232 необходимо согласовать логические уровни. И соединять надо приемник с передатчиком!)
Как то так.

Comment: Спасибо! Но я ничего не понял. То есть логические уровни?

Comment: Ну у Вас для МК логический нуль - 0-1,1 В, а лог 1 - 3.6-5.5 В по моему, а для ком порта:
уровень логической единицы – от +5 до +15В, уровень логического нуля – от -5 до -15В

Comment: И вообще чем можно управлять с помощью этих процессоров?

Comment: Не процессор а микроконтроллер, это разные вещи! Управлять можно практически всем, все будет зависеть от разрядности, тактовой частоты, памяти и периферии которая есть у этих МК. Но обычно проектируют модули. А чем управлять, посмотрите здесь, я накрапал недавно:
http://hashcode.ru/research/219498/javascript-как-запустить-котел-на-си