# Как определить значение АЦП на языке C?

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, avr

В процессе программирования микроконтроллеров AVR появилась необходимость измерения напряжения и передачи его на ПК. Передачу на ком порт я освоил по ранее заданному вопросу, сейчас хотелось бы узнать как измерить напряжение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для определния значения напряжения у МК должен быть встроенный АЦП, но по моему в прошлом вопросе Вы говорили что используете AtMega32, так вот у него аж 8 каналов. Ниже приведу программу для определения значения напряжения, но прежде попытаюсь разъеснить что к чему на Вашем конкретном МК. Каналов, как я сказал, восемь. АЦП 10 разрядный, но можно в настройках установить 8 разрядов. Точность измерения АЦП вплоть до младшего значения, то есть если мы берем 10 разрядный АЦП, то у него 1023 младшие единицы, а значит при опорном напряжении 5В точность будет 5000 мВ/1023 т.е. приблизительно 4мВ. В настройках необходимо будет указать частоту дискретизации.
Так значит перейдем к ПО. Описывать особо не буду, всю информацию сможете подчеркнуть в комментариях.

```
#include <mega32.h> 
 #include <delay.h> 
 #include <stdio.h> 

 //Определим название канала с которого мы и будем считывать значение АЦП
 #define ADC_0 0


 // функция read_adc() и будет нам возвращать значение АЦП
 unsigned char read_adc(unsigned char adc_input) 
 { 
 ADMUX=adc_input | (ADC_VREF_TYPE & 0xff); 
 //Задержка необходимая для стабилизации значения АЦП
 delay_us(10); 
 // Преобразование значения
 ADCSRA|=0x40; 
 // Ожидаем окончания обработки
 while ((ADCSRA & 0x10)==0); 
 ADCSRA|=0x10; 
 //Возвращаем значение АЦП
 return ADCH; 
 } 

int adc; //Переменная которая будет хранить в себе текущее значение АЦП

 void main(void) 
 { 
 //Настраиваем МК
 PORTA=0x00; 
 DDRA=0x00; 
 PORTB=0x00; 
 DDRB=0x0C; 
 PORTC=0x00; 
 DDRC=0xC3; 
 PORTD=0x00; 
 DDRD=0x88; 
 TCCR0=0x6B; 
 TCNT0=0x00; 
 OCR0=0x5F; 
 TCCR1A=0x00; 
 TCCR1B=0x00; 
 TCNT1H=0x00; 
 TCNT1L=0x00; 
 ICR1H=0x00; 
 ICR1L=0x00; 
 OCR1AH=0x00; 
 OCR1AL=0x00; 
 OCR1BH=0x00; 
 OCR1BL=0x00; 
 ASSR=0x00; 
 TCCR2=0x6C; 
 TCNT2=0x00; 
 OCR2=0x5F; 
 MCUCR=0x00; 
 MCUCSR=0x00; 
 TIMSK=0x00; 
 UCSRA=0x00; 
 UCSRB=0x18; 
 UCSRC=0x86; 
 UBRRH=0x00; 
 UBRRL=0x19; 
 ACSR=0x80; 
 SFIOR=0x00; 

  // Инициализация АЦП
 // Частота преобразования: 125,000 kHz 
 // Ножка на которую будет подаваться опорное напряжение: AVCC pin 
 ADMUX=ADC_VREF_TYPE & 0xff; 
 ADCSRA=0xA7; 
 SFIOR&=0x1F; 


while (1) 
 { 
//Присваиваем текущее значение АЦП переменной adc
adc = read_adc(ADC_0);
//Отправляем на ПК полученное значение, которое на нем вы сможете преобразовать в напряжение по формуле (adc/1023)*Vref, где Vref - опорное напряжение МК
printf("%d\n\r ADC= ", adc);
//Устанавливаем задержку после каждой отправки
delay_ms(1000);
 }
 }
```

Как принимать и отправлять я отвечал Вам в предыдущем вопросе: 
[Как на Си передать информацию от микроконтроллера на COM- порт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/219987/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-com-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Попробовал все работает!

Comment: А как быть если я выберу 8 разрядов?

Comment: ADMUX=ADC_VREF_TYPE & 0xff; 
 ADCSRA=0x80; 
 SFIOR&=0x1F;
Это в настройках, а максимальное значение АЦП станет 255. Алгоритм пересчета тот же, и все остальное остается так же. Но для разных МК различные регистры и естественно иногда будут различные значения тех параметров что я указал